# untrunc error while repairing mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've tried to recover a corrupt .mp4 file using ffmpeg and untrunc on Ubuntu 14.04.

The first simply doesn't work, I get: "Invalid data found when processing input."

On the other hand, untrunc recovers about half the video, and then I get: "[aac @ 0xccfa00] Error decoding AAC frame header."

Any suggestions as to how to recover the whole file?

Comment: You ... already said it's a corrupted file. So restore from a backup would be the easiest.

Comment: Well, I don't know the technical meaning of that word, the file only doesn't play. The only "backup" I've got is the SD card on my phone.

Comment: So copy it from that SD card if it plays fine on your phone? A corrupted file could have any kind of damage. Random data written into it, flipped bits, missing bits etc.. What did you use to play it?

Comment: Only the first 40 seconds play on my phone. Using utrunc on my laptop I am able to recover about 5 minutes out of a total of 10. I have copied the file four or five times from my phone to my laptop and repeated the operation, always getting the result copied above: "[aac @ 0xccfa00] Error decoding AAC frame header." If this is not clear, maybe I should edit the question?

Comment: Well you didn't really include any information about what you tried aside from the very general mention of programs you used. Maybe include some information about the commands you actually used. If the file behaves that way it's probably damaged. As for [`untrunc`](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) how did you get a similar undamaged file?